# PHP for loop Show the entries in ascending order by quantity

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

The second **foreach**-function is displayed in every `<td>` x-Times because of the **for**-function.
What must the second foreach be replaced with so that it is only shown once per `<td>`?

```
echo '<div class="responsive">';
echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Bestellung #</th><th>Lieferant</th><th>Vsl. WE</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tbody>';
foreach($arr->entries as $order => $value) {
    echo '<th scope="row">' . $value->id . '</th>';
    echo '<td scope="col">' . $value->contactSender->accounts[0]->companyName . '</td>';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $arr->totalsCount; $i++) {
        foreach($arr->entries[$i]->dates as $order => $value) {
            if($value->typeId == 11) echo '<td scope="col">' . $value->date . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: The `for` loop is iterating over the same array `$arr->entries` as the first `foreach` loop. Why do you need another loop over the same array?

Comment: I don't need another loop. But I'm not sure how to output the `foreach` content without a new loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop is iterating over `$arr->entries`, so you're crossing every element in that array with each other. Just use a second `foreach` loop that iterates over the `dates` array.

Also, don't reuse the `$value` iteration variable in the nested loops. It doesn't seem to cause any problems here, but it's confusing.

```
echo '<div class="responsive">';
echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Bestellung #</th><th>Lieferant</th><th>Vsl. WE</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tbody>';
foreach($arr->entries as $value) {
    echo '<th scope="row">' . $value->id . '</th>';
    echo '<td scope="col">' . $value->contactSender->accounts[0]->companyName . '</td>';
    foreach($value->dates as $value2) {
        if($value2->typeId == 11) echo '<td scope="col">' . $value2->date . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```